# GAM y-axis to display response variable?

Tags: r, visualization, gam

I am hoping to get some help with GAMs in R. I've seen other people have a similar issue, but unfortunately I get very lost trying to understand the existing solutions and apply them to my situation. I would greatly appreciate any help!

The data I'm plotting are the rating responses of several participants (Subjects) over time, recorded at 1-second intervals.

I used this code to create and plot the GAM:

`model1<-gam(Rating~s(Time)+Subject,data = c1152,method = "REML")`

`plot(model1)`

Here is the resulting plot: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy4Vf.png)

I would like to generate a plot with the response variable (Rating) on the y-axis, instead of the smooth (not sure what the correct term is?) that is displayed there now.

Thank you in advance!

*Edit*: @Roland, here is my updated code:

```
DF <- data.frame(Time, Rating, Subject = factor(Subject))
fit <- gam(Rating ~ s(Time)+ Subject, data = DF)
ggplot(DF, aes(Time, Rating, color = Subject))+
  geom_point() +
  lapply(unique(DF$Subject),
         \(Subject) stat_function(fun = \(Time) predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(Time, Subject)),
                            aes(color = {{Subject}}))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you want to plot the predictions. You can use ggplot2 and `stat_function` for this:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- 1:100
g <- 1:5
y <- 5 * g + sin(x/10) + rnorm(100)

DF <- data.frame(x, y, g = factor(g))

library(mgcv)
fit <- gam(y ~ s(x) + g, data = DF)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y, color = g)) +
  geom_point() +
  lapply(unique(DF$g),
         \(g) stat_function(fun = \(x) predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x, g)),
                            aes(color = {{g}}))
         )
```

[image: resulting plot, showing a scatter plot with the simulated data and predictions from the GAM as lines]

---

**Edit:** OP has clarified that they actually want a mixed-effects model. Random effects are implemented as smoothers in mgcv and can be specified with `bs = "re"`. Read [Hierarchical generalized additive models in ecology: an introduction with mgcv](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/#hierarchical%7Cgams) (Pedersen et al., 2019) for an overview of hierarchical GAMs and the different options you have of modelling this.

```
fit <- gam(y ~ s(x) + s(g, bs = "re"), data = DF)
summary(fit)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y, color = g)) +
  geom_point() +
  #population-level prediction
  stat_function(fun = \(x) predict(fit, 
                                   newdata = data.frame(x, g = factor(1)),
                                   #newdata needs to contain a value for g, but it is not used
                                   exclude = "s(g)"),
                aes(color = "population")) +
  #subject-level predictions
  lapply(unique(DF$g),
         \(g) stat_function(fun = \(x) predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x, g)),
                            aes(color = {{g}}), linetype = 3)
  )
```

[image: resulting plot, showing a scatter plot with the simulated data and predictions from the GAM at subject level and population level as lines]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I was able to get this to work, but I need the plot to show one GAM for all of the subjects (rather than show individual lines for each subject). I added my code to the main post-- could you tell me how to adjust it to show one smooth for all subjects?

Comment: Does that mean you want subject to be a random effect? With the proposed model in your question, I don’t know what you mean by “show one GAM for all of the subjects”.

Comment: In this case, yes, I think subject should be considered a random effect. With the code you gave, the graph shows the smooth function for each level of the factor (subject), but I would like it to just show the GAM without this differentiation by subject. Thank you, and sorry if this doesn't make much sense!